# Unable to locate package php5-mysqlnd-ms

Tags: php, mysql

Using Ubuntu Server 16
PHP5.5 FPM
PHP Version 5.5.35-7+donate.sury.org~xenial+1

Trying to install Wordpress:
Your PHP installation appears to be missing the MySQL extension which is required by WordPress.

I have un-commented sql lines from php.ini of FPM 5.5

Trying to install mysqlnd-ms:

```
sudo apt-get install  php5-mysqlnd-ms
sudo apt-get install  php5.5-mysqlnd-ms
sudo apt-get install  php7-mysqlnd-ms
sudo apt-get install  php-mysqlnd-ms
```

Getting error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package php5-mysqlnd-ms
```

Comment: php 5 is gone ;P do `php7.0-mysqlnd-ms`

Comment: @SeverusTux , I already tried it and got error:

    E: Unable to locate package php7.0-mysqlnd-ms
    E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'php7.0-mysqlnd-ms'
    E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php7.0-mysqlnd-ms'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For PHP 5.6 and 7.0, you are out of luck, because upstream hasn't released PHP 7.0 compatible version of `mysql_ms`.

For PHP 5.5, I have released a package called `php-mysqlnd-ms` into the main PHP PPA and you should be able to install it with:

```
sudo apt-get install php-mysqlnd-ms
```

However I would recommend using something else for your MySQL load-balancing as PHP 5.5 security support will end in June 2016 and you will have to find some other option anyway as you don't want to be using a software without security fixes.

Answer (score 1):

I tried `sudo apt-get install php-mysqlnd` and it said I need to explicitly choose one to install. So this worked for me:

`sudo apt-get install php5.6-mysql`

Don't forget to restart apache